# "Bring to front" for Windows XP command shell

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-shell

Is there a command I can put into a Windows XP .bat file to bring the command shell to the front?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a batch file, no. If you want to activate a window you have to use [SetActiveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646311(VS.85).aspx). If you don't want to get dirty with Windows programming, but still want to activate windows and simple stuff like that, I highly recommend checking out [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml). You could always call this program from your batchfile to have it do the task.

Answer (score 12):

[nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) will do this, though it involves a little scripting.

```
nircmd win activate "titleofwindow"
```

You basically need to know the title of the cmd window you are executing (you can set this via the TITLE command in windows)

thus:

```
TITLE %SOME_UNIQUE_VALE%
nircmd win activate %SOME_UNIQUE_VALE%
```

should do the trick.

Note some malware tools make use of the NirCmd executable (it requires no deployment and is very powerful); this may cause you problems.

Comment: For some reason, I needed to specify title: nircmd win activate title "TITLE"

Comment: There appears to be a bug in the current release (v2.8.6.231) of NirCmd that causes the activated window to lose its maximization state.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get the cmd prompt window to show in front is by ending file1.bat with a command to call a second file2.bat file, followed by an exit command.

EXAMPLE using 
file1.bat

```
....
[your code here]
start C:\file2.bat
exit
```

This closes file1.bat and opens a second .bat file where you can continue with your code. This second .bat command prompt will open in front of other windows

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and I had to develop a simple C# console application that brought a Window to the front. The window is selected using the window title passed as an argument.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr handle);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);
        const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        public static void bringToFront(string title)
        {
            // Get a handle to the Calculator application.
            IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, title);

            // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (IsIconic(handle))
            {
                ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Founded ");
            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
                bringToFront(args[0]);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("specify program window title");
        }
    }
}
```

The code of my batch script is then something similar to:

```
tasklist  /FI "IMAGENAME eq program.exe" | find "program.exe"
if errorlevel 1 (program.exe) else (BringToFront.exe "Program Window Title")
```

Answer (score 3):

[CMDOW](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) is also useful for this and for other DOS programming tasks where a little added functionality is needed.  Simple to use and well documented.  Mind your anti-virus program, though - CMDOW has the ability to hide windows which your anti-virus program will pick up as a possible virus.  Just add it to your exception list.  CMDOW is completely portable, is definitely NOT a virus and if you have any concerns about it being used by a third party to hide something, simply tuck it away in some non obvious folder somewhere.

Comment: Many years later, this link is now broken.  Anyone have an official link?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [focusOn.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/focusOn.bat)

```
call focusOn.bat "My Title"
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Also, Stack Overflow answers are supposed to be self-contained. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64789685/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -1):

Another quick way to switch to a window by name is via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which opens [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)). Then just type the first few letters of the windows title to select the process, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is a pretty great tip! Just one problem... it'll open with whichever tab was most recently open. If it was the "Application" tab, great, but if it's another tab, you'll need a more elaborate set of keystrokes... it looks like if you do `Ctrl+Shift+Esc`, that'll launch Task Manager. `Shift+Tab` will select the tab bar. Hitting the left arrow a few times results in the Applications tab eventually being selected (and since it doesn't loop and that's left most, you're good.) `Tab` to get back to the list, type the name of the window, and hit `Enter`.

Comment: If someone thinks I'm crazy for thinking that's useful, automating keystrokes is super easy and has very few external library dependencies. Python alone is enough to automate keystrokes. Reading windows coordinates and automating the mouse, on the other hand, is very tricky. So automation solutions that can work with nothing but keyboard input are great. Also, hitting the left arrow several times can be replaced with hitting home once.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc, wait for 1 second, press Alt+Tab can be an easier option.